# Why is line of code being executed many times in a single spark executor

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark job which is reading from kafka. 
I have 32 executors. 
In a mapping transformation I am referencing an object Foo. 
In Foo it needs to do initialisation on the first transform operation (example below).
I would expect the initialisation to happen once per executor. 
However it happens 16 times per executor.
Why would this be?

```
object Foo extends Serailizable {
    var init = false     

    def transform(){
       if(!init){ 
          sleep(1000)
          init = true;
       }
    }
}
rdd.map(Foo.transform(_))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make the initialisation as singleton which will make sure it will happen once per JVM(once per executor.)